# Case status "status class" - what is it used for?

Tags: civicase

I can see that the status class (opened or closed) will end case role relationships, but is it used for anything else?

edit for clarification: Each case status has a "status class" - open is "opened" and resolved is "closed" by default. The only effect that changing a case status to resolved/closed that i can see, beyond that status, is that case role relationships are assigned an end date and so are inactive, so i'm wondering if this status class is used anywhere else that i've not noticed.

Reason being - i am considering removing "closed" status class from all status types, so that case role relationships are maintained whatever the status and can be ended manually if necessary instead.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail to your question? I find it hard to determine what you are actually asking here.

Comment: Have edited the original question, hopefully makes more sense now.. (and my reason for asking)

Comment: Don't fully understand your use case. perhaps you could explain the work flow further

Comment: My cases are sometimes re-opened, looked at by others etc. after they have been resolved, and the default behaviour makes it harder to work out who was involved with the case originally, because the relationships have been assigned an end date on case resolve.
I've edited the "status class" for all case statuses to be "opened", so relationships are never ended, unless manually. I can still find resolved cases by searching for a status of resolved/closed.
This seems to have worked fine as far as i can tell so i'm assuming that "status class" was indeed only used for ending relationships.

Comment: Since the time this question was originally asked it's become clearer that something got introduced that changed the way roles are displayed on manage case for closed cases - they didn't used to "disappear". The most recent proposal on this is here https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/542

Answer (score 0):

If you remove it, then how would you close a case? It won't recognize the Change Case Status activity as actually closing the case.

If you want relationships to exist outside of a case then you can use regular non-case relationships. That's really the only technical difference between roles and relationships. And relationships can still have start/end dates if you need to record that.

And you can still see regular relationships on the manage case screen, under the Other Relationships accordion.

Comment: If closing a case (ie using a case status with status class "closed") only affects the case role relationships, i don't see the benefit over just searching for cases with status "resolved" - unless somewhere in civi uses it?

Benefit to me of keeping cases technically open is that the case roles are preserved and can be easily seen when viewing a "closed" case. At the moment, you need to search through activities or relationships to see who the case manager etc was. 


I don't want to use the regular relationships for cases as i can't set specific required roles and users will forget.

Comment: In most scenarios, we close a case to indicate we've 'finished' something. That workflow, whatever we set up, is completed. So being able to see how many are still open vs. how many we've finished is important. It seems you're using CiviCase as a workaround for something else, not necessarily for a pre-set workflow - so this may be warranted for you but keep in mind other functionality may come in the future that affects more than just relationships attached to cases.

Comment: This is old but stackexchange bumped it so just adding that the "bug" about not seeing roles when a case is closed is still outstanding - see also https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1401